# I want to exclude a specific file from the the user account security of windows 10

Tags: windows-10, security

When I open a specific file it gives me this windows-message:

https://ibb.co/HTyrcPQ

How can I exclude this warning for this file? It comes from User account security. The method which I exclude this file in windows security<virus and thread protection, doesn't worked.

Comment: More details needed. cmd.exe itself never asks for elevation, so my guess is that you are running a script.